# Postgresql Multi tenant database architecture

Tags: postgresql

We are designing a business intelligence application that will store data from multiple customers. We wish of course to keep each customer's data secure. In most cases a customer should only be able to view their own data but in rare cases a user might have permission to see more than one customers  data and a selected few of our own employees need to  to be able to see and analyse all the data from all customers. We also need to be able to restrict data access below the company level so for example we might want to restrict the data a user can see to data from a specific country or city.
The database structure for all customers will be identical and if we change the structure it will apply to all customers.
This is a specialist application that will never have a huge no of customers probably 10 or less or maybe 30 in our wildest dreams. Currently our database structure has 78 tables but the actual data size for each customer is relatively small, most likely megabytes maybe a gig max.
We understand their are various options, separate databases, single database with schemas, row level security and combinations of these but despite plenty of googling and seeking advice from experts we still don't have a definitive answer to  what would be the best architecture to achieve our goals.
The database will be accessed by 2 applications, a stand alone C# program used to populate the database from various sources and a web dashboard/reporting application written in PHP/Laravel, ideally we would like the same security/login password to function on both.
Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question and provide more technical details to further narrow down the question? At the moment this seems to concern purely the style. At the moment the question is simply too broad to provide a worthwhile answer, without saying that: "It depends :)"

Answer (score 1):

> @tippoWe understand their are various options, separate databases,
> single database with schemas, row level security and combinations of
> these...

We had the same problem to chose. It ended up that the max isolation of each customer was extremely important to us. So we chose separate databases. One advantage (besides security) was that we could move, maintain and restore each individual database separately.

The only issue is when updating tables, columns, views etc. You have to do this by a separate routine for each database.

Comment: Thanks! So are you also able to view and data across all the customers databases?

Comment: Yes and No. The simplest way is to manually log out from db1 and log in to db2. Or you can do a program script that logs in to and fetches data from several databases. And if you use Postgresql, there is a add on that lets you view data from several databases.